RevenueCat - Payment was charged after that revenue cat threw RECEIPT_ALREADY_IN_USE
Scenario Description
I am using the "Keep with original App User ID" feature as it suits my requirements. Here are the steps I followed in a sandbox environment:
User A purchased a monthly subscription using Apple account X.
After a successful purchase, User A logged off.
User B then attempted to purchase a yearly subscription using the same Apple account X.
After the payment was charged (payment completed successfully) to User B, RevenueCat threw the error: RECEIPT_ALREADY_IN_USE. There is no use in this, either the error should threw before the payment was charged or the payment should not be completed successfully.
Question
How can I restrict the user from making a payment if the subscription is already linked to another user ID, thereby preventing the payment charge before it occurs?

If user b is using the same Apple ID as user A and the subscription is auto renewing then there was no additional charge to user x

In my case UserA buys a monthly subscription and UserB buys a yearly subscription then it would be charged after that RevenueCat threw the error: RECEIPT_ALREADY_IN_USE.

Those two subscriptions should be in the same subscription group, so user X is actually changing their subscription term to yearly; when the renewal date is reached, they will renew for a year and this will be applied to user A since you have chosen "keep with original app id".

You should check whether there is an active subscription for the Apple ID before showing the purchase screen. If there is a current subscription then check with your back end to see if it is associated with the current app user. If it is, show the manage subscriptions screen. If not then inform the user that they already have a subscription linked to a different app account.

Is there any possibility to validate the receipt associated with the current app user in the mobile-end without the help of back-end (web hook) ?

Yes. You can get the receipt. It is even easier if you can use StoreKit 2 but it depends on your minimum ios target
